# Will casting an "integer" float to int always return the closest integer?

Tags: python

I get a float by dividing two numbers. I know that the numbers are divisible, so I always have an integer, only it's of type float. However, I need an actual int type. I know that `int()` strips the decimals (i.e., floor rounding). I am concerned that since floats are not exact, if I do e.g. `int(12./3)` or `int(round(12./3))` it may end up as 3 instead of 4 because the floating point representation of 4 could be 3.9999999593519561 (it's not, just an example).

Will this ever happen and can I make sure it doesn't?

(I am asking because while reshaping a numpy array, I got a warning saying that the shape must be integers, not floats.)

Comment: why don't you simply use integer division?

Comment: Yeah I just thought of that right after I posted. Was about to update the question, but I'll let your comment do the talking instead.

Comment: Though, if I do e.g. 3.5/0.5 then that's not possible. (I don't, I divide two integers, but for the sake of argument...)

Comment: Casting a float to an int will always return the int you expect if your expectations are tuned to the semantics of the language. How can we possibly know if your expectations match the semantics of the language since you don't explain what your expectations *are*?

Comment: @JohnColeman, thanks, I updated the title now. I think the meaning came through adequately in the question when looking at the example but one can never be too clear, and the title was vague.

Comment: I roughly knew what you were talking about, but was somewhat confused since your question itself suggested that you knew the difference between `int()` and `int(round())` (although the `int` around the later would be pointless - at least in Python 3)

Comment: Detail: "since floats are not exact,"  --> `float` _numbers_ are exact.  It is `float` _operations_ that do not always return the exact mathematical result.

Comment: @chux: Actually, float numbers are emphatically **not** "exact", in the way most people think of exact. If a number cannot even be accurately represented as a float, then it's not what most people would call exact. There is **no such thing** as a binary float that is **exactly** equal to our human, decimal notion of `0.1`, for example.

Comment: @JohnY When I evaluate `type(round(3.999))` in Python 3, I get the ouput `<class 'int'>`  but `type(4.0)` yields `<class 'float'>`

Comment: @JohnColeman: You're right. I'm sorry, they did change that for Python 3, when you provide no 2nd argument. If you do `round(3.999, 0)`, you get 3.0 rather than 3.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks, didn't know that Python 3 did that. I'm using Python 2 due to some dependencies I rely upon for daily usage, but I need to support both Python 2 and 3 for the packages I release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting a `float` to an `integer` truncates the value, so if you have `3.999998`, and you cast it to an `integer`, you get `3`.

The way to prevent this is to round the result. `int(round(3.99998)) = 4`, since the round function always return a precisely integral value.

Comment: How can the round function return a precisely integral value when it returns a float?

Comment: A float is like decimal number with limited length, except with binary digits instead of digits 0-9.  It can hold integer values precisely, like 3453.0.  There are lots of numbers it can't hold precisely, like 1/3 = 0.3333..., because its length is limited.

Comment: @cmeeren: The thrust of this answer is correct, **for your stated question**. It's true that `round` will not give "intuitive" results where the float value is close to a rounding boundary, such as `round(2.675, 2)` (this example is given right in the documentation). But your question specifically stipulates that you know your values should be integral, and these will round as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Rounding can be simulated by adding 0.5 to the value in question. For example:

```
>>> int(3.4)
3
>>> int(3.7)
3
>>> int(3.4 + 0.5)  # 3.9
3
>>> int(3.7 + 0.5)  # 4.2
4
```

Comment: In C, adding 0.5 to round a number fails for 1) many negative numbers,  2) The number just smaller than 0.5, 3) many `float`numbers with ULP of 0.5 4) many `float` value with ULP of 1.0.  Suspect similar troubles with python.

Comment: None of these special cases are generated by the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using integer division (`a//b`) since I divided integers. Wouldn't have worked if I divided e.g. 3.5/0.5=7 though.